# How to store data in array from web api

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, jsonparser, iosdeployment

I am using Xcode 11.3.1,  Swift 5 and trying to show data in table view through web api. So after fetching the data I want to store "name" data in countryList. countryList is an array.

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

```
        do
        {if error == nil{

            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary
            let tableData = parsedData?["data"] as! NSArray

            self.countryList = [tableData.value(forKey: "name") as? String]
            print("DEVELOPER: \(self.countryList)")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.countryTable.reloadData()
            }
            }
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }.resume()
```

//Web Api

{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "Algeria",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "American Samoa",
            "id": 4
        }
],
    "message": "List of all countries."
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
guard let data = data else { return }
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
let tableData = parsedData["data"] as! [[String:Any]] 
self.countryList = tableData.compactMap {  $0["name"] as? String }
```

Recommenced

```
do { 
   let res = try JSONDecoer().decode(Root.self,from:data)
    print(res.data)
 }
catch {
   print(error)
 }
```

---

```
struct Root : Codable {
   let status:Int
   let data:[Model]
}

struct Model:Codable {
  let name:String
  let id:Int
}
```